# Python wrapper install gives "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"

Tags: python-2.7, binding, pip, setuptools, libffi

I've been trying to install this Python wrapper for the past two days. I went through all the other questions here on Stack Overflow. Tried literally everything, and nothing seems to work.

```
Processing /../../../../../wrappers/Python
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip-twPZdY-build/setup.py", line 50, in <module>
    **cffi_args
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 319, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 386, in finalize_options
    ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
  File "/private/tmp/pip-twPZdY-build/.eggs/cffi-1.10.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 188, in cffi_modules
    add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
  File "/private/tmp/pip-twPZdY-build/.eggs/cffi-1.10.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 49, in add_cffi_module
    execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
  File "/private/tmp/pip-twPZdY-build/.eggs/cffi-1.10.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(code, glob, glob)
  File "../ffi_build.py", line 34, in <module>
    ffi.set_source('../_ffi', None)
  File "/private/tmp/pip-twPZdY-build/.eggs/cffi-1.10.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/cffi/api.py", line 612, in set_source
    raise ValueError("'module_name' must not contain '/': use a dotted "
ValueError: 'module_name' must not contain '/': use a dotted name to make a 'package.module' location

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-twPZdY-build/
```

I've reinstalled everything at least twice, updated, tried sudo -H, but nothing seems to work. It seems like a problem with setuptools, but I have no idea how to fix it.

- Mac OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan)
- Python 2.7.13
- Pip 9.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully reading through the error message, I managed to find the file called ffi_build.py under the Python folder I was trying to bind. As stated in the error message, at line 34 there was a module naming statement that contained a '/'. By replacing that '/' with a '.' I solved the issue and managed to bind the Python wrapper with no issue whatsoever.